# Issue using React Hooks on an axios call

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm making a basic weather app with React, and having an issue getting my `setWeather` to update `weather`. I had read that setState doesn't update state the first time it's called, and that seems consistent with the empty object that `console.log(weather)` returns. `cityData` returns the full response, as expected, but `weather.name` and non-nested data (i.e. only strings, not arrays or objects) functions properly, which is unexpected.

I would like to know how to get `setWeather` to perform as advertised, and why the arrays and objects that the API return are showing as undefined.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const Search = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

    const findCity = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&units=imperial&appid=${APIKEY}`)
        .then(res => {
            const cityData = res.data;
            console.log(cityData);
            setWeather(res.data);
            setQuery('');
            console.log(weather)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>App</h1> 
            <p>Get the weather in your city!</p>

                <form onSubmit={findCity}>
                        <input 
                            type='text' 
                            className='city-search'
                            placeholder='What city are you looking for?'
                            name='city-name'
                            onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
                            value={query}
                        /> 

                    <button
                        type='submit'>
                        Get City
                    </button>
                </form>
            <h1>{weather.name}</h1>
        </React.Fragment>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do `console.log(weather)` in the submit handler because the submit handler is still using the old weather (i.e. from current render). Do this instead:

```
const Search = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

    const findCity = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&units=imperial&appid=${APIKEY}`)
        .then(res => {
            const cityData = res.data;
            console.log(cityData);
            setWeather(res.data);
            setQuery('');
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    console.log(weather) //<-- THIS IS THE ONLY THING I'VE CHANGED

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>App</h1> 
            <p>Get the weather in your city!</p>

                <form onSubmit={findCity}>
                        <input 
                            type='text' 
                            className='city-search'
                            placeholder='What city are you looking for?'
                            name='city-name'
                            onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
                            value={query}
                        /> 

                    <button
                        type='submit'>
                        Get City
                    </button>
                </form>
            <h1>{weather.name}</h1>
        </React.Fragment>
    )

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was showing that weather was being updated in the return statement, but thank you for confirming that the submit handler was using the old value. It looks like SO cut off the bottom of the code for my followup question.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&units=imperial&appid=${APIKEY}

Are you passing the query and APIKEY here. If not please add them as well to your axios call. Am assuming that your getting an invalid response. APIKEY has to be provided to get a successful response from the Weather API.

Comment: No issue passing my query and API key. The data I get back is consistent with the openweathermap api responses. Thank you for the thought!